# Transistor connection

Tags: arduino, transistors

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZVnbO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[original schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjJ65.jpg)

I tried to give my lcd screen 12v in arduino but this connection burned the arduino. Is there anything wrong with connections?

Comment: This site has a built in circuit editor. Please use it.

Comment: Difficult to see from the drawing, but it looks like your BJT is shorting the 12V Vin to ground when it turns on.  A real schematic would really help in trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

From the schematic, when the transistor is turned on, puts a short-circuit on the 12V rails.

The basic circuit to activate something with a transistor is

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGyZie.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In the figure, shown as an LED may be activated with an NPN transistor, connected to the PWM control output.
The main thing to keep in mind is that the transistor defines two parts of the circuit. The input circuit, where the PWM signal that activates and deactivates the transistor is connected.
The output circuit where the load (LED) and power supply that is used to activate the load is connected. The transistor operates in this case as a switch for closing the load circuit.
When the PWM signal is high, the transistor behaves like a closed switch. When the PWM signal is low, the transistor does not conduct.

In the schematic of photography, the collector is directly connected to the power supply of the LED, so that when the PWM signal is high, a short circuit occurs in the power supply.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a problem. the lcd is directly connected to a 12V potential.
And transistor has no control over it.

The right thing is to connect the '-' pin of the lcd to collector of the transistor. not to GND.

Also the collector connection to 12V must be removed.

Comment: ahhh. I have trouble using the schematic editor. I try to post it as soon as possible.

Comment: So, I'm not using Vin?

Comment: Oh. I am late. He posted a schematic. use his answer.